# Selenium - How to fill a value and click a button

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I started today with selenium, and I'm having a problem at finding these elements and filling a value in the first and clicking the second.

```
<input class="inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Che nome vuoi usare?" maxlength="999" value="">
```

```
<input class="inputDefault-3JxKJ2 input-3ITkQf" type="checkbox" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;">
```

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# Content to fill - <input class="inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Che nome vuoi usare?" maxlength="999" value="">
# {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="Che nome vuoi usare?"]"}

# Checkbox - <input class="inputDefault-3JxKJ2 input-3ITkQf" type="checkbox" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;">

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://discord.gg/NGvXRfrmUE")
name = driver.find_element_by_class_name("inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To").send_keys("Test")
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("inputDefault-3JxKJ2 input-3ITkQf").click
```

And I get this exception for the first

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To"}
```

And this for the second

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".inputDefault-3JxKJ2 input-3ITkQf"}
```

Comment: Have you tried this: open dev tools and selecting the element, and then right click and copy xpath.

And then driver.find_element_by_xpath('path')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `name` is available, you should use `name attribute`.

```
driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys("Test")
```

I could see this HTML at my end :

```
<input class="inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To inputField-4g7rSQ" name="email" type="text" placeholder="" aria-label="Email or Phone Number" autocomplete="off" maxlength="999" spellcheck="false" value="">
```

so here `name` is `email`, so one should try :

```
driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys("Test")
```

**Update 1  :**

```
driver.get("https://discord.com/invite/NGvXRfrmUE")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys('Test')
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I got this error
```    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="username"]"}```

Comment: Can you try this `driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys("Test")` ?

Comment: Can you try that with explicit waits, check out the update1 section